# Count exclusive and shared product_ids for each merchant_id

Tags: sql, presto

For each `merchant_id` I would like to count `product_id` that exist both in `store_a` and `store_b` which is then classified as a `'shared_product`

And count `product_id` that exist only in `store_a` or `store_b` respectively which is then classified as `'exclusive_product_storeA'` or `'exclusive_product_storeB'`

My query does not show  the `shared_product` , it only shows `'exclusive_product_storeA'` and `'exclusive_product_storeB'`

Please not there are only **store_a** and **store_b** but multiple **merchant_id**'s

**Table**

```
merchant_id   product_id    store_id    product_status
1             8328          store_a     new_product
1             4234          store_a     new_product
1             8328          store_b     new_product 
1             4234          store_b     new_product
1             5943          store_b     old_product

2             1244          store_a     old_product
2             1244          store_b     old_product
2             2353          store_a     old_product 
2             2353          store_b     old_product
2             5943          store_a     new_product

3             9838          store_a     old_product
3             9838          store_b     old_product
3             1244          store_a     old_product
3             1244          store_b     old_product
3             6544          store_a     old_product
3             6544          store_b     old_product
3             3443          store_a     old_product
```

**Output table**

```
merchant_id    product_status   product_state              count_product
1              new_product      shared_products             2
1              old_product      exclusive_product_storeB    1

2              old_product      shared_products             2
2              new_product      exclusive_product_storeB    1

3              old_product      shared_products             3
3              old_product      exclusive_product_storeA    1
```

**Query**

```
select merchant_id, product_status, product_state, count(*) as cnt
from (select merchant_id, product_id, product_status,
             (case when max(store_id) <> min(store_id) then 'shared'
                   when max(store_id) = 'store_a' then 'only store_a'
                   else 'only store_b'
              end) as product_state
      from t
      where store_id in ('store_a', 'store_b)
      group by merchant_id, product_id, product_status
     ) mp
group by merchant_id, product_status, product_state;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can classify the products using window functions and then aggregate:

```
select merchant_id, product_status, product_state, count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             (case when min(store_id) over (partition by product_id) = 
                        max(store_id) over (partition by product_id)
                   then min(store_id) over (partition by product_id) || ' only'
                   else 'both'
              end) as product_state
      from t
      where store_id in ('store_a', 'store_b')
     ) mp
group by merchant_id, product_status, product_state;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e62eb7fdbfce8d2a8658485c56ac1d3f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: the query does not identify 'shared' products - which are products that are present in store_a and store_b - it only identifies the exclusive ones

Comment: @user12625679 . . . You have no examples of products that are in both stores for a given `merchant_id` -- which is *exactly* what your question is asking for.  English may not be your first language, so I can understand how that might be less clear.  Based on your comment, you don't want products per merchant, just products overall.  I removed the `merchant_id` from the `partition by` so `'both'` is calcualted.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I have updated the example  and output table. Hope this makes it clear